# Creating a better translation for a node.js api to ruby

Tags: api-design, node.js, ruby

My client has a nodejs SDK that fetches `entries` using a client that makes http requests. Their api looks like this:

```
    var Query = Client.ContentType('blog').Query();
    Query
      .where("title", "welcome")
      .includeSchema()
      .includeCount()
      .toJSON()
      .find().then((response) => resolvePromise etc...))
```

I have been tasked with mirroring this api but in an idiomatic way in ruby.

My earlier attemps at doing `entries = client.entries({content_type: 'blog'})` were rejected. They now want me to now write an api that reads like this:

```
query = client.content_type('blog').query;
entries = query
              .where("title", "welcome")
              .include_schema
              .include_count
              .to_json
              .find;
```

Somehow this doesn't make sense to me (perhaps due to the level of misdirections involved) and I don't exactly know why.

If I write a method like `content_type('content_uid')` on my client class, I am writing a parameterized setter that already breaks rules.

If you are a rubyist, does this look like good api design to you? How can I improve on this?

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a transliteration, and Class modeling and practice in Ruby is much different and holistic than JavaScript.  The JavaScript idiom is more of a data representation than Ruby's OO classes and objects.

The plus to transliteration is it is shorter time to deliver a working product, but it won't be idiomatic Ruby in anything other than method names.

This looks like interaction with a query builder.  One way you could attack this with a meta approach.  Write ruby that implements the interface they want but uses the bridge pattern to already existing ruby query builder (Rails or Active Record).